# How can I separate each cube with different Data?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I made a cube that shows different info of the customer on each side of the cube. There are 6 different customers but only one cube with that customer info is showing up. The rest is hidden for some reason. How can I make those cubes appear with that customer data?

I've tried an array and a foreach. Nothing is working.

function drawCube(Data) {
            $('#wrapD3Cube').append($('').has(D3Cube));

```
        var custList = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
            var custList = Data[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < Data.length; j++) {
                drawCube([" + i + "][" + j + "] =  + custList[j]);

                custList += '<div id="side1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1.05; background-color: #D5D8DC; width: 112px; height: 112px; " ' + i + Data[i].Customer + "'> </div>"

                custList += '<div id="side2" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1.05; background-color: #81C784; width: 112px; height: 112px; font-size: 11px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;  " ' + i + "'>";
                custList += '<table class="table table-sm table-light"><thead><tr><td>Customer ID</tr></td></thead></table>  ';
                custList += Data[i].Customer;
                custList += "</div>"
                custList += '<div id="side3" style="position: absolute; opacity: 2.05; background-color: #FFF59D; width: 112px; height: 112px; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; " ' + i + "'>";
                custList += '<table class="table table-sm table-light"><thead><tr><td>Inserted Time</tr></td></thead></table>  ';
                custList += Data[i].Time;
                custList += "</div>"
                custList += '<div id="side4" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1.05; background-color: #EF9A9A; width: 112px; height: 112px; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; " ' + i + "'>";
                custList += '<table class="table table-sm table-light"><thead><tr><td>Status</tr></td></thead></table>  ';
                custList += Data[i].Status;
                custList += "</div>"
                custList += '<div id="side5" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1.05; background-color: #B2EBF2; width: 112px; height: 112px; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; " ' + i + "'>";
                custList += '<table class="table table-sm table-light"><thead><tr><td>Assign To</tr></td></thead></table>  ';
                custList += Data[i].Agent;
                custList += "</div>"
                //custList += "<br>";
                custList += '<div id="side6" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1.05; background-color: #D5D8DC; width: 112px; height: 112px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;  " ' + i + "'>";
                custList += "</div>"
                // custList += "<br>";
                // else {
                //custList += Data.length + i + "<br>";
                //break;

            }
        }

        document.getElementById("D3Cube").innerHTML = custList;
```

Each cube has different customer data but only one cube shows up. There should be many cubes depending on how many customers are waiting.

Comment: Could you add a code snippet

Comment: @Phanti not sure how I would do that here.